# How to write over or across a TextField in JavaFX2?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a large number of textfields in tabs on screen - each of them must be validated. If there is an error in the input, I want some indication that a specific field has an input error.

Not every culture understands that red border means error, so I need to have the text 'error' somewhere near, over or across. For instance, to have a titled border over the text field in red saying 'error' like [Java Swing has](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/components/BorderDemo3.png). So in the base class of the tab controllers - TabController, I have methods like

```
validateNumber(TextField field, String validRangeRegex); 
validateIpaddress(TextField field, String validRangeRegex);
```

This question asks the same but the solution involves subclassing from StackPane.
[GroupBox / TitledBorder in JavaFX 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860960/groupbox-titledborder-in-javafx-2/14864021)

How do I implement titled border without subclassing from TextField?

If it isn't possible in raw JavaFX, I was wondering if a [JavaScript handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#script_event_handlers) can write "error" over the text field?
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#script_event_handlers

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just give the textbox an error style class with a red background-color? And install a tooltip on the textbox where the error occurred?

I know this might not be a direct answer but I don't think it is possible without subclassing.

Installing tooltip:

```
TextBox t = (TextBox) o;
t.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Please enter a value"));
t.getStyleClass().add("error");
```

CSS:

```
.error {
    -fx-background-color: #FBE3E4;
    -fx-text-fill:#8a1f11;
}
```

Comment: I need to have the words "error" near or over the TextField. Not everyone understands a red border is error. Changed the question title to say "How to write over or across a TextField in JavaFX2?"

Answer (score 0):

I found this question - I shall use an image icon that says "error".
[Adding a small picture on the right side of textField with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159156/adding-a-small-picture-on-the-right-side-of-textfield-with-css)