# Why can't this css statement in Java FX2 code find the image file?

Tags: javafx-2

Statement 1 gets image file from css and fails to find the image file even though I supply an absolute url. Why?

The image file location is correct because in statement 3, it works.
This is a further query of a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159156/adding-a-small-picture-on-the-right-side-of-textfield-with-css/13159511#13159511) posted by jewelsea.

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldCssSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setId("textField");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(textField);
        // 1) following statement **fails**. resources folder is below the root level folder
        textField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-background-image:url('/resources/pumpkin-icon.png'); -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat; -fx-background-position: right center;");
        // 2) following statement succeeds in finding a http url. 
        //    textField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-background-image:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rockettheme/halloween/32/pumpkin-icon.png'); -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat; -fx-background-position: right center;");
        // 3) following statement succeeds finding image file. 
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/resources/pumpkin-icon.png"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update: cnahr's workaround worked! I have also opened a JavaFX bug report.RT-31131**

Comment: Which absolute URL can you use to access your image on your server?

Comment: Are you able to access the image on your server using a browser?

Comment: @eepp This is a JavaFX application on the desktop - no server.

Comment: Is the `resources` directory a direct child of `src`?

Comment: @eepp yes My Documents\NetBeansProjects\TryFXApplication\src\resources

Comment: @eepp Also look at statement 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the leading slash in the inline CSS URL.

Seriously. I just experimented a bit, and found that an image embedded in the JAR would load only when the *complete* URL was specified as a *relative* URL within an inline CSS like (1).

However, when I used an Image constructor as in (3) then I could either omit or include the leading slash. The image would load fine regardless.

So I think you just found a bug in the JavaFX CSS parser. :)

---

Note: [RT-31131 Inline CSS statement in Java FX2 code can't find the image file when absolute path is used](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31131) was closed as a duplicate of [RT-21697 CSS: Absolute paths in url("...") without a scheme should be relative to the classpath](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21967), which was resolved for the Java 8 release, so the CSS processing error has been fixed in later JavaFX releases.

Comment: I first thought, "this is a crazy suggestion". But then I tried it and it worked! I have opened a JavaFX bug report here. https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31131

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and bug report, I had feared it might be just a freak occurrence in my test program. Truly a weird bug...

Comment: How does one erase the image? I tried `-fx-background-image: null;` but that does not work.

Comment: "none" is the canonical CSS name for no image, try that.

Comment: I did try it - doesn't work. `-fx-background-image: none;` Can you please try with your test program?

Comment: "none" works for me, just as you wrote it. I suggest you open a new question for this.