# Put text in background of JavaFX node

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169383/2850115) explains how to put a background image inside a TextField. However, I would like to know how to put arbitrary text as background, and do it without CSS, if possible. My first idea was to take a snapshot of Text node and use it as a background image, as follows (I am doing this inside a constructor of a class extending TextField):

```
Text text = new Text("TEST");
text.setFill(Color.RED);
WritableImage image = text.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
this.setBackground(new Background(
        new BackgroundImage(
                image,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                new BackgroundPosition(Side.LEFT, 3D, false, Side.TOP, 50, true),
                new BackgroundSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false, false, false, false))));
```

However, it doesn't work. Background gets completely grayed out, and even the border disappears. Any idea how to do this? CSS solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Sometimes it helps to just put the question here, it gets you thinking. :-)

There were three problems. First, I had to use existing background as a base for new background. Second, I used vertical position incorrectly, I thought if you set it to 50% it will center it vertically, but apparently not. And finally, you can't do this in constructor because background doesn't exist yet, so I had to wrap it inside Platform.runLater(). Here is the revised code.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Text text = new Text("TEST");
        text.setFill(Color.RED);
        WritableImage image = text.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        double imageVPos = (getHeight() - image.getHeight()) / 2;
        BackgroundImage backImage = new BackgroundImage(
                image,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                new BackgroundPosition(Side.LEFT, 7D, false, Side.TOP, imageVPos, false),
                new BackgroundSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false, false, false, false));
        List<BackgroundImage> images = new ArrayList<BackgroundImage>();
        images.add(backImage);
        setBackground(new Background(getBackground().getFills(), images));
    }
});
```