# How do I limit the number of characters visible in a text field at a time to less than the textfield's width?

Tags: java, css, javafx, background-image, textfield

I have included an image in my JavaFX `TextField` by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159156/adding-a-small-picture-on-the-right-side-of-textfield-with-css) post, but now my problem is that the text can overflow to cover up the image, like this:

[image: Textfield text overlaps on image]

What I want to do is, instead of the `TextField` moving & cutting off the text when I get to the edge of the `TextField`, it should start cutting off visible text when I get to the left edge of the image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to set the padding on the right side of your `TextField` to account for the image:

```
-fx-padding: 4px 25px 4px 7px;
```

This will keep the default padding for the `top`, `bottom`, and `left`, while updating the `right` value. The `25px` here may need to be adjusted based on your image, but here's my example:

```
textField.setStyle(
        "-fx-background-image: url('resources/play.png');" +
        "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;" +
        "-fx-background-position: right center;" +
        "-fx-padding: 4px 25px 4px 7px;"
);
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Didn't even think about that. Thanks so much! That works.

Comment: How do you make sure only the right side padding is affected?

Comment: @trilogy The `-fx-padding:` attribute takes 4 values. I keep all of them at the default 5px and only update the second one, which corresponds to the right side. I believe they are, in order, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`.

Comment: @Zephyr oh is 5px always the default?

Comment: @trilogy - No, I hadn't looked up the actual original values but just went with what looked close. Per `modena.css`, a `TextField` has the following default padding: `0.333333em 0.583em 0.333333em 0.583em` or `4 7 4 7`

Comment: I think `em` is a multiplier to the default font size. Therefore, I'm wondering if leaving the original values in `em`'s and then making the right padding based on how large the image is, rightly in pixels: for example: `-fx-padding: 0.333333em 25px 0.333333em 0.583em;` Would that be best? Too bad JavaFX doesn't have `-fx-padding-right`

Comment: That would be fine as well, @trilogy.